# How to rename table name in SSIS using Execute SQL Task editor?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a set of data loaded into a standard table, now I want to rename that table based on a variable name. I want to rename to create new table everytime I run the process based on the variable name.

```
exec sp_rename 'xx.oldtable', ?
```

when I try to parse the query I get compilation error which doesn't make sense. I have set the parameter to the use variable too.

[image]

Comment: Put BypassPrepare to True.

Comment: @ThomA - wow! that worked. thanks but why? what's the difference .. I was trying to see if the syntax is correct or not.

Comment: In my experience, SSIS doesn't parse parametrised queries well. `EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.SomeTable', N'AnotherTable';` would parse fine.